# redirect to a child theme based on the town of Internet users in france with the verification of the ip address

Tags: redirect, child-theme, localization, ip

How to redirect to a child theme and what is the best solution?

I have a main theme and a child theme, the main theme will be intended only to the resident of my municipality and the child theme to all other Commons. The goal is to speak only of news for residents of the municipality and services at other Commons only.

Therefore, a redirect based on the type of content and not on the basis of the language.
If you can explain how this system works and tell me on how to integrate it into wordpress, thanks

Comment: Salut, wouldn't be a [multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) solution better suited for your case? I mean rather than switching to a child theme (which is not really intended for that in first place)...

Comment: If you think multisite solution is better for you, update your question in consequence please :)

Comment: i have a multisite theme : symetrio from themeforest.

Comment: Sorry, it's just a multitheme and not a multisite.I do not have the utility of a multi site for the site that I created

Comment: Themes are just for the **appearance**. While you want to serve different **content** defined by some conditions, you better take the multisite approach, you can then redirect each IP to the corresponding individual site which will serve the correct content. "WP Multisite" option is just an option, it virtualizes multisites under only **one** physical WP install with the benefit to have different databases for each site.

Comment: Sorry, i would like to redirect an url and not only a specific content.

Answer (score 1):

A parent and a child theme haven't been designed to do this. 
In your case you need to create template file for your tags (cities) i.e: single-paris.php, and load it with `template_redirect` filter, according to the request. 
Another way to achieve it, is to add a body class that will call another css values, but you'll have less possibilities.

Comment: is it the only solution ? I will see the filter "template_redirect" but there is not a way to target a url and give redirection settings? where can I find the codes to locate by common ip addresses?

Comment: No, I don't think it's the only solution, but that's how I would do. When you talk about child-theme, I was thinking that you talk about template. On the init hook you may run a geo-localization script, and load the right template according to the user's location. But, there's a browser limitation, user need to accept the geo-localization...

Comment: I thought that the ip localization is realized before the surfer see the website . it should be not necessary to let the user to accept localization ? How do TV channel to restrict content based on the country of the user ? If i go on the American Fox Channel never asked me to allow my location !

Comment: htaccess redirection base on ip prefix, there is many way to do (http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/tutorial/), this is not the way I understood your question.

Comment: I think I found the interval corresponding to my city ip addresses!
Can i use them inside htaccess, or directly inside geoip2 api ?
I have seen this page :
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript
I'm trying to understand the workings of geoip2, but I don't see any use of ip address and the specified location is not at all accurate